# HTTP headers - Requests - Python

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website in which the request headers are having some new (for me) attributes such as `:authority, :method, :path, :scheme`.

```
{':authority':'xxxx',':method':'GET',':path':'/xxxx',':scheme':'https','accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8','accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br','accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9','cache-control':'max-age=0',GOOGLE_ABUSE_EXEMPTION=ID=0d5af55f1ada3f1e:TM=1533116294:C=r:IP=182.71.238.62-:S=APGng0u2o9IqL5wljH2o67S5Hp3hNcYIpw;1P_JAR=2018-8-1-9',   'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT6.1;Win64;x64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,likeGecko)Chrome/68.0.3440.84Safari/537.36',   'x-client-data': 'CJG2yQEIpbbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEI2J3KAQioo8oBCIKkygE=' }
```

I tried passing them as headers with http request but ended up with error as shown below.

> ValueError: Invalid header name b':scheme'

Any help would be appreciated on understanding and guidance on using them in passing request.

EDIT: 
code added

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=some+text'

headers = {':authority':'xxxx',':method':'GET',':path':'/xxxx',':scheme':'https','accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8','accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br','accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9','cache-control':'max-age=0','upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT6.1;Win64;x64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,likeGecko)Chrome/68.0.3440.84Safari/537.36',   'x-client-data': 'CJG2yQEIpbbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEI2J3KAQioo8oBCIKkygE=' }

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Please include your code, so that the error might get reproduced.

Comment: Header names are not supposed to contain colons, since colons are used as a delimiter in headers.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti Code added.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks for noticing. But still i did not get the proper response. Can you elaborate about those header attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error comes from [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5ca6d7469be53960843df39bb900e9c3359f127f/Lib/http/client.py#L1249) (python's source code)

Http headers cannot start with a semicolon as RFC states.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have removed them and code works fine now. But still i did not get the proper page response yet. Can you help in it?

Comment: why do you need these headers?

Comment: I am trying to get the response of the webpage. So trying different methods. I found these headers as strange and thought these might be the reason for not getting the response.

Comment: maybe the page is render with javascript so you need something like selenium or https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer

Comment: Sure. I will check these.

Answer (score 1):

:authority, :method, :path, :scheme are not http headers

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

```
':method':'GET'
```

defines http request method

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

and

`:authority, :path, :scheme`

are parts of URI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax

Comment: Are they playing any role in getting a web page's response?

Comment: yes, but you are using them elsewhere in your code. requests.get() represents method, and url = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=some+text' is your URI (www.google.co.in is an authority, https is a schema and /search is a path.